# Locally integrable functions versus distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

We know that every locally integrable functions on $\mathbb R^n$ defines naturally a distribution. Moreover, every distribution is differentiable.

I think the following is right:

The fundamental solution to the Laplacian on $\mathbb R^n$ is locally integrable, hence defines a distribution. For example, in $n=3$, we have:
$$
\phi(x)=C_3|x|^{-1}
$$
And
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_j^2}=C_3'[-|x|^{-3}+3x_j^2|x|^{-5}],
$$
which is still a distribution but fails to be locally integrable. Am I right?

Comment: If the distributional derivative $\partial_{jj}\phi$ is represented by a measurable function, then so would be the same for the sum $\Delta \phi = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \partial_{jj} \phi$, which is not true since $\Delta \phi = \delta$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So where was my calculation for the second derivative wrong? If I am correct, then $\Delta \phi(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$. How can I recover the identity $\sum_j \partial_{jj}\phi=\delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of computation shows that, for any test function $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{1}{|x|} \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial x_j^2}(x) \, dx
= -\frac{4\pi}{3}\varphi(0) + \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}(0)} \varphi(x) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j^2}\frac{1}{|x|} \, dx. $$

If you want to replicate this result, you can utilize the divergence theorem to compute both

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}(0)} \operatorname{div}\left( \frac{1}{|x|} \, \mathrm{e}_j \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} (x) \right) \, dx
\qquad \text{and} \qquad 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}(0)} \operatorname{div}\left( \varphi (x) \, \mathrm{e}_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{1}{|x|} \right) \, dx. $$

and then let $\epsilon \downarrow 0$.

Here, the failure of local integrability of $\partial_{jj} \frac{1}{|x|}$ near $x = 0$ is reflected in the emergence of the extra Dirac delta term $-\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta$. This is also where the distributional derivative departs from the ordinary differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

Distributions are linear functionals on the space of test functions.
When you write $\phi(x)=C|x|^{-1}$ is a distribution, what you mean
is that it defines the distribution
$$f\mapsto \int_{\Bbb R^3}\phi(x)f(x)\,dx.$$
(Here $f$ is smooth of compact support).

As a distribution, the second derivative of $\phi$
with respect to $x_i$ is the functional
$$f\mapsto \int_{\Bbb R^3}\phi(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i^2}(x)\,dx.$$

If the support of $f$ does not contain the origin then integration
by parts gives you
$$\int_{\Bbb R^3}\phi(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i^2}(x)\,dx
=\int_{\Bbb R^3}\psi(x)f(x)\,dx\tag{*}$$
with
$$\psi(x)=C(-|x|^{-3}+3x_i^2|x|^{-5}).$$
What this means is that $\psi$ is the second derivative of $\phi$
(wrt $x_i$) on $\Bbb R^3-{(0,0,0)}$. The formula $(*)$ fails
to define $\partial^2 f/\partial x_i^2$ for test functions $f$
whose support includes the origin, since $\psi$ is not $L^1$ in a neighbourhood of the origin.

To prove that $\phi$ is a fundamental solution of Laplace's equation
what one must show is that
$$\int_{\Bbb R^3}\phi(x)\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1^2}(x)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2^2}(x)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3^2}(x)
\right)\,dx=f(0,0,0)$$
whenever $f$ is a test function. Try using spherical polars...